# WCF Webservice slow, find bottleneck

Tags: web-services, wcf, profiling

I'm briefly familiar with SvctraceViewer, but I'm not sure that is the right tool for this. Problem is, I'm trying to work with a rather large WCF app, not designed nor developed by me. Also, it is poorly documented.

Some of the views are running slowly, but - I have no idea why.

Is there any program that I can use to find out where the bottleneck is? 

How many milliseconds a task takes before completing and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use any profiler. There's nothing magical about WCF services which requires a special tool.

I have used both the built-in profiler in Visual Studio and also the dotTrace product from Jetbrains to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. Messed around a bit with dotTrace from Jetbrains, but found the built in analyzer tool in VS2010 to be just as good. Found the bottleneck :)

Answer (score 2):

+1 to John Saunders - a profiler is the way to go to diagnose your problem. [Ants Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) is also excellent. I think you can get a 15 day free trial - might be long enough to identify your problem